# count repeated data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need to count the times that two values are repeated in the dataframe and create a column that has that count:

I have this example dataframe:

| date | cod | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20210127 | 29 | h |
| 20210127 | 29 | h |
| 20210126 | 26 | h |
| 20210125 | 26 | h |

I need this:

| date | cod | type | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20210127 | 29 | h | 2 |
| 20210126 | 26 | h | 1 |
| 20210125 | 26 | h | 1 |

I try this like that :

```
df['count'] = df.apply(lamba x: df.count() if date and cod)
```

Comment: `df = df.groupby(['date', 'cod', 'type'], sort=False).size().reset_index(name='count')` (as outlined in [this answer](/a/32801170/15497888))

Comment: `df = df.value_counts().reset_index(name='count')` (as described in [this answer](/a/62802626/15497888))